# � odd character

Tags: html

� Odd Character when request file via ajax method and also Ext.ajax.request.Only problem on firefox browser.Internet Explorer 8 and Chrome no effect.The file i request come from windows iis server.

Answer (score 2):

Try saving the file as UTF-8 encoding with signature on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem when I copy paste text into my html from various places like word files or email. In particular I find a have problems with the apostrophes. So double check that and as others have said it is an encoding issue.